# jQuery UI Draggables - constrain movement by NOT allowing drag inside an area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm currently using jQuery UI draggables on this page, to drag words into relevant boxes. http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/register-username-builder.php

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgT3R/1)

It uses `constrain` to keep you within the general div of the page, you can't drag outside that area.

As is (hopefully) obvious, it is intended that you drag one green word into the green box, one purple into the purple etc. However, I want to do a couple of things. Essentially using `constrain` but round the other way. I want to NOT allow dragging into boxes for certain colours e.g:

- Word from (1) can be dragged into box (1) only. It will just hit the edge of the purple box.
  Same goes for other colours. Try and drag them into the wrong box and they'll just be stopped at the edge.
- `if statement` that once an item is dragged into the box, nothing can be dragged into it again. Unless you remove the word, then it will be useable again (to limit one word per box).

This is the basic code I have so far for the draggables:

```
// Draggies
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#dragArea", scroll: false });
$( ".slot.one" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    $(".tick.one").fadeIn("fast");
  }
});
$( ".slot.two" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    $(".tick.two").fadeIn("fast");
  }
});
$( ".slot.three" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    $(".tick.three").fadeIn("fast");
  }
```

});

Each tile and box uses `.slot.one` and `.word.one` to define them as different so it's doable to script for each one (1, 2 or 3) independently.